# Activity back stack - Keep the first lanched activity and clear others

Tags: android, android-intent, back-stack

Here is the situation. A is the first activity launched by the app.

Given A -> B, if I call activity F, it becomes A -> F clearing B.

However, there are cases such as calling F from A -> B -> C. It should again resolve into A -> F. Therefore I believe FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY would not work.

**Edit**:
Clarification
Structure would be like,

A (launch)

B D F (2nd level, A -> B, A -> D, or A -> F)

C E (3rd level, A -> B -> C or A -> D -> E)

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: In your second example, does pressing back in C go back to B or A?

Comment: It would go back to B.

Comment: So is it only the case that F clears the stack and all other activities behave normally?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify my problem. Basically, I don't want to clear the launcher activity A. The back button will work normally in all activities.

Comment: I guess I don't really understand what the issue is. Activity A will not be cleared if it is the launch activity unless you hit the back button while in Activity A.

Comment: What I'm struggling with is, given A -> B -> C and calling F, `to remove B and C to add F without clearing A`. Does this make sense?

Comment: @awonderer Were able to achieve this, even I am having the same kind of implementation and stuck on that. Please add it as an answer if you could ever achieve.

Answer (score 1):

When you are at A->B and want to start F, invoke finish() on B and then startActivity(F). Your backstack will then be A->F.

If your stack is larger (A->B->C) and you want it to become A->F, you could do use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to bring the task back to A and then invoke whatever you need from the root.

Something like this

```
class A {
    public void onStart(){
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent != null && intent.contains(EXTRA_INVOKE)){
            startActivity(Class.forName(intent.getExtra(EXTRA_INVOKE)));
        }
    }

    public static void restoreStackTo(Context context, Class<? extends Activity> clazz){
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, A.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_INVOKE, clazz.toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and use it as

```
A.restoreStackTo(F.class)
```

from C when the stack is, say, A->B->C.